# Tensor Product Of $L^p$ Spaces Is Dense In The Product $L^p$ Space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, tensor-products

I want to prove the following:

> **Proposition:**
> Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{B}, \nu)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and let $(X\times Y , \mathcal{A} \otimes  \mathcal{B} , \mathcal{\mu}\otimes \mathcal{\nu})$ be the product measure space. Further let $p \in [1, \infty) $. Then $$\overline{L^p(X) \otimes L^p(Y)} =  L^p(X \times Y), $$ where the closure is with respect to the norm in $L^p(X \times Y)$.

Here $L^p(X) \otimes L^p(Y)$ is identified with a subspace of  $L^p(X \times Y)$ through the natural embedding $f \otimes g  \mapsto \big( (x,y) \mapsto f(x) g(y) \big) $.

I have proven the statement in the special case when $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite (not $\sigma$-finite) and my question is:

**Is my proof of the finite measure case correct and if it is, how can i adapt it to the case where the measures are $\sigma$-finite?**

**My proof (of the finite case):** It suffices to show that $\chi_C \in \overline{L^p(X) \otimes L^p(Y)} $ for every $C \in \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$ with $\mu \otimes \nu (C) < \infty$. Here $\chi_C$ denotes the indicator function of the set $C$. This is because the linear combinations of such indicators are dense in $L^p(X \times Y)$.

Now assume that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are finite (and hence also $\mu \otimes \nu$), then we can use the following theorem, which is proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228998/approximating-a-sigma-algebra-by-a-generating-algebra):

> **Theorem:** Let $(X,\mathcal B,\mu)$ be a finite measure space. Let $\mathcal A\subset \mathcal B$ be an algebra generating $\cal B$.
> Then for all $B\in\cal B$ and $\varepsilon>0$, we can find $A\in\cal A$ such that $$\mu(A\Delta B)<\varepsilon.$$

Here $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference: $A \Delta B = (A \setminus B ) \cup (B\setminus A) = (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$.

To use the theorem define
$$\mathcal{E}_0 =  \{ A \times B : A \in \mathcal{A}, B \in \mathcal{B}  \}$$
and
$$\mathcal{E} = \big \{ \bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i : C_i \in \mathcal{E}_0 , n \in \mathbb{N}  \big \}.$$
Then $\mathcal{E}$ is an algebra that generates $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$.
Clearly the indicator functions of all elements of $\mathcal{E}_0 $ are in $L^p(X) \otimes L^p(Y)$, because they have product form and finite measure.
The indicator function $\chi_E$ of every member $E$ of $ \mathcal{E}$ is also in $L^p(X) \otimes L^p(Y)$, because $E$ can be written as a finite and disjoint union of sets in $\mathcal{E}_0$ and then $\chi_E$ is just the sum of the indicator functions on these rectangle sets.

Now let $ C \in \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$. Then by the theorem there exist for every $\varepsilon >0$ an $E \in \mathcal{E}$ so that $ \mu \otimes \nu (C \Delta E )< \varepsilon $ and therefore
$$ \| \chi_C - \chi_E \|= \| \chi_{C \Delta E} \| = \big( \mu \otimes \nu (C \Delta E ) \big)^{1/p} < \varepsilon^{1/p},$$
which concludes the proof.

My idea to extend the proof to the $\sigma$-finite case is that the $\sigma$-finite case can perhaps be reduced to the finite case by restricting the product measure space in some suitable way to make it finite. But i could not come up with a suitable restriction.

Comment: If your space if sigma-finite, then you can write $X=\bigcup_n E_n, Y=\bigcup_m F_m$ where $(E_n)_n, (F_m)_m$ are increasing and of finite measure. Pick $f\in L^p(X\times Y)$ and set $g_k(x,y)=\chi_{E_k}(x)\chi_{F_k}(y) f(x,y)$. We have $g_k\rightarrow f$ in $L^p(X\times Y)$ by dominated convergence. By the finite case you can approximate $g_k$ by linear combinations of products of indicator functions in $L^p$ and you are good to go. I leave it to you to fill in the details.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks for the proof suggestion. I managed to prove the result. I really have to remember the construction of the sequence $g_k$. I am sure it can be used in many places to transfer results from finite to $\sigma$-finite cases.

Comment: You are very welcome. Indeed, this trick is pretty neat and allows quite often to pass from the finite to the sigma-finite case.

Comment: I think that the statement *"The indicator function $\chi_E$ of every member $E$ of $\mathcal{E}$ is also in $L^p(X) \otimes L^p(Y)$"* maybe not correct. Let $X=Y=\mathbb R$. Let
$$
E = (\{1\} \times \{1\}) \cup ( \{2\} \times \{2\}).
$$
Then
$$
1_E (x, y)=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if} \quad (x,y) =(1, 1) \, \text{ or } \, (x,y) =(2, 2), \\
0 &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
I could not find $f \otimes g \in L^p(X) \otimes L^p(Y)$ such that $f \otimes g =1_E$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Could you please have a check on my above comment?

Comment: @Akira if i am not mistaken in your case we have $1_E = 1_{ \{ 1\} \times \{ 1\}  } + 1_{ \{ 2 \} \times \{ 2 \}  }$ which is in the tensor product

Comment: @jd27 Can you give the explicitly form of the associated $f,g$?

Comment: @Akira $1_E (x,y) = 1_{ \{ 1 \} } (x)  1_{ \{ 1\}  }(y) + 1_{ \{ 2 \} } (x) 1_{ \{ 2 \} } (y)$

Comment: @jd27 From you natual embedding $f \otimes g  \mapsto \big( (x,y) \mapsto f(x) g(y) \big)$, we have $h \in L^p(X) \otimes L^p(Y)$ IFF there are $f \in L^p(X), g \in L^p(Y)$ such that $h(x, y) = f(x) g(y)$. I don't think $1_E (x, y) = 1_{ \{ 1 \} } (x)  1_{ \{ 1\}  }(y) + 1_{ \{ 2 \} } (x) 1_{ \{ 2 \} } (y)$ can be written in that form. You only show that $1_E (x, y)$ can be written as the *sum* $f_1(x)g_1(y) + f_2(x)g_2(y)$.

Comment: @Akira the tensor product is the linear span of all elements of the form $f \otimes g$ (it is a vector space). The action on simple tensors then defines the embedding by linearity.

Comment: @jd27 Ah I'm sorry for my misunderstanding. Now I got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the suggestion of Severin Schraven i managed to solve the problem:

Since $(X, \mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{B}, \nu)$ are $\sigma$-finite there exist sequences $(E_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(F_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of increasing measurable sets each having finite measure with $X = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E_n$ and $Y=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n$.

Let $f \in L^p(X \times Y)$. Define a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $L^p(X \times Y)$ functions by
$f_n = \chi_{E_n \times F_n} f$.
Now let $(x,y) \in X \times Y$. Then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty } \chi_{E_n \times F_n} (x,y) =  \lim_{n \to \infty } 
 \chi_{E_n} (x) \chi_{F_n} (y) =1,
$$
because there exist some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $x \in E_m$ and $y \in F_m$ and then the same is true for all larger $n$ as well.
Therefore $f_n \to f$ pointwise.
Since $|f_n| \leq |f |$ the theorem of dominated convergence gives $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\| f- f_k \|< \varepsilon$. Now $f_k$ is zero outside of $E_k \times F_k$.

To proceed with the proof we need the following results:
For a $\sigma$-Algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on a set $X$ and $C \in \mathcal{A}$ define the restricted $\sigma$-Algebra $\mathcal{A}|_C$ on $C$ by
$$ \mathcal{A}|_C = \{ A \cap C : A \in \mathcal{A} \}.$$
Now let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathcal{A}$ then
the map
\begin{align}
i: L^p(C, \mathcal{A}|_C, \mu ) & \longrightarrow L^p(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu ) \\
f & \longmapsto \bigg( x \mapsto 
\begin{cases}
f(x), \quad \text{if} \ x \in C, \\
0, \quad \text{else.}
\end{cases} 
\bigg)
\end{align}
is a linear isometry, which can be easily verified on indicators and is then true for all (by density).

Now back to the proof: The measure spaces $(E_k, \mathcal{A}|_{E_k}, \mu)$ and $(F_k, \mathcal{B}|_{F_k}, \nu)$ are finite and furthermore $ \mathcal{A}|_{E_k} \otimes \mathcal{B}|_{F_k} =(\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B})|_{E_k \times F_k}$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074304/restriction-of-the-smallest-sigma-algebra-lieb-and-loss-theorem-1-4)).

By the finite case there exist a $g \in L^p( E_k)  \otimes L^p(F_k)$  with
$\| g- f_k|_{E_k \times F_k} \|_{E_k \times F_k} < \varepsilon$. Applying $i$ gives $\|i(g) -f_k \|<  \varepsilon $.
Furthermore $i(g) \in L^p(X) \otimes L^p(Y)$ and
$$\|f-i(g) \|  = \| f -f_k + f_k - i(g) \| \leq \| f-f_k\| + \|f_k- i(g) \| < 2 \varepsilon.$$

Comment: Very nice proof. The only (irrelevant) detail that you could think about is that if you pick $f\in L^p(X\times Y)$ then you can (if we are pedantic) not talk about $f(x,y)$ unless you fix a representation.