# Orthonormal basis of $L^2(X \times Y)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathscr{S}, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathscr{T}, \lambda)$ be two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. Let $\{ \phi_i\}_{\in I}$, $\{\psi_j\}_{j \in J}$ be two orthonormal bases for $L^2(X,\mu)$ and $L^2(Y, \lambda)$ respectively. For $i \in I$, $j \in J$, let
$$\theta_{ij}(x,y):=\phi_i(x)\psi_j(y), \,\,\,\, (x\in X, y \in Y).$$

Is it true that $\{\theta_{ij}\}_{i \in I, j \in J}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2(X \times Y, \mu \times \lambda)$ ?

Answer is yes whenever either $L^2(X)$ or $L^2(Y)$ is separable. See for instance the following.

[Orthonormal basis for product $L^2$ space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105451/orthonormal-basis-for-product-l2-space?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The question is precisely for the case when both $L^2(X)$ and  $L^2(Y)$ are not separable i.e. both $I$ and $J$ are uncountable.

Comment: Thanks peek-a-boo for ur comment. It will be helpful if u can give the answer or at least a reference.

Comment: Thanks peek-a-boo. You have fixed it nicely.

Answer (score 2):

This follows from a general result on the tensor product of Hilbert spaces.

> **Proposition:** Let $\mathcal{H}_{1}, \mathcal{H}_{2}$ be Hilbert spaces and $M_{i} \subset \mathcal{H}_{i}$ with $\overline{ \operatorname{span} M_{i}} = \mathcal{H}_{i}$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$. Then $\overline{ \operatorname{span}  \{ \varphi \otimes \psi : \varphi \in M_{1} , \psi \in M_{2} \} } = \mathcal{H}_{1} \hat{ \otimes} \mathcal{H}_{2} $.

Here $\mathcal{H}_{1} \hat{ \otimes} \mathcal{H}_{2} $ denotes the [Hilbert space tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces#Definition).

**Proof**: Let $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \varphi_{i} \otimes \psi_{i} \in \mathcal{H}_{1} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{2}$ and $\varepsilon >0$.
For $i  \in \{1 , \dots , n\}$ let  $\varphi_{i}^{\prime} \in  \operatorname{span} M_{1} $ and $\psi_{i}^{\prime} \in \operatorname{span} M_{2} $ with $\| \varphi_{i} - \varphi_{i}^{\prime} \| \| \psi_{i} \| < \varepsilon$ and $\| \psi_{i} - \psi_{i}^{\prime} \| \| \varphi^\prime_{i} \| < \varepsilon$ ( first choose $\varphi^\prime_i$, then $\psi^\prime_i$).
Then:
\begin{align*}
 &\bigg \| \sum_{i=1}^{n} \varphi_{i} \otimes \psi_{i}  -\sum_{i=1}^{n} \varphi^{\prime}_{i} \otimes \psi^{\prime}_{i}  \bigg \|
 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \| \varphi_{i} \otimes \psi_{i}  - \varphi^{\prime}_{i} \otimes \psi^{\prime}_{i}   \|\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \| (\varphi_{i} - \varphi^{\prime}_{i}) \otimes \psi_{i}  +  \varphi^{\prime}_{i} \otimes( \psi_{i} - \psi^{\prime}_{i})   \| \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \big( \| (\varphi_{i} - \varphi^{\prime}_{i}) \otimes \psi_{i} \|  + \|  \varphi^{\prime}_{i} \otimes( \psi_{i} - \psi^{\prime}_{i})   \| \big) < 2n \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
The proposition follows since $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \varphi^{\prime}_{i} \otimes \psi^{\prime}_{i} \in \operatorname{span} \{ \varphi \otimes \psi: \varphi \in M_{1}, \psi \in M_{2} \}$ and because $\mathcal{H}_{1} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{2} $ is dense in $\mathcal{H}_{1} \hat{\otimes} \mathcal{H}_{2} $.

It follows that $ ( \psi_i \otimes \varphi_j)_{(i,j) \in I \times J}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}_1 \hat{\otimes}\mathcal{H}_2$ for an orthonormal basis $(\psi_i)_{i \in I}$ of $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $(\varphi_j)_{j \in J}$ of $\mathcal{H}_2$ with arbitrary index sets $I,J$.

Since $L^2(\mu) \hat{\otimes} L^2(\lambda) = L^2( \mu \times \lambda)$ the original statement follows. For a proof see my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4737770/tensor-product-of-lp-spaces-is-dense-in-the-product-lp-space).

Comment: @Muna Triangle inequality  and using the fact that in general $\| \psi \otimes \varphi \| = \| \psi \| \| \varphi\|$ as well as the assumption on the summands.

Comment: i understood the idea and can do it myself. See the last line carefully. You have  assumed  $\|\psi_i−\psi'_i\|\|\phi_‖<\epsilon$ in the begining but u need  $\|\psi_i−\psi'_i\|\|\phi'_\|<\epsilon$

Comment: @Muna Ah, yes. I have fixed the assumption.